# cloud-init per-boot script on ubuntu ec2-instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-11.10, cloud-init

I am trying to start a script with cloud-init on a ubuntu 11.10 ec2 instance.

I put the script `script.sh` in the folder `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot`.
Content of `script.sh` is simple:

```
#/!/bin/sh 
echo "test"
```

After a reboot, I get the following error:

```
run-parts: failed to exec /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/script.sh: Exec format error
run-parts: /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/script.sh exited with return code 1
2012-04-14 19:10:52,642 - cc_scripts_per_boot.py[WARNING]: failed to run-parts in /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot
2012-04-14 19:10:52,648 - __init__.py[WARNING]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/CloudConfig/__init__.py", line 108, in run_cc_modules
    cc.handle(name, run_args, freq=freq)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/CloudConfig/__init__.py", line 72, in handle
    [ name, self.cfg, self.cloud, cloudinit.log, args ])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/__init__.py", line 309, in sem_and_run
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/CloudConfig/cc_scripts_per_boot.py", line 27, in handle
    util.runparts(runparts_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 140, in runparts
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(sp.returncode,cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '['run-parts', '--regex', '.*', '/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot']' returned non-zero exit status 1

2012-04-14 19:10:52,648 - __init__.py[ERROR]: config handling of scripts-per-boot, None, [] failed

cloud-init boot finished at Sat, 14 Apr 2012 19:10:52 +0000. Up 3.70 seconds
2012-04-14 19:10:52,672 - cloud-init-cfg[ERROR]: errors running cloud_config [final]: ['scripts-per-boot']
errors running cloud_config [final]: ['scripts-per-boot']
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your problem is related to the fact that `#/!/bin/sh` is not a valid input type. Need to remove the / after the #.

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo "test"
```

Let me know if you still see the problems after this.

Comment: Thank you, that was one of these typical simple and silly errors :D